# Is there any way to use target="_blank" inside Link tag in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Am using Link tag to redirect my page to another page in new tab but target="_blank" is not working !

```
<Link onClick={(e) => { 
              e.preventDefault();
              localStorage.setItem("_queryID",cases["_id"])
              this.props.history.push("/content") 
              }} target="_blank">
      {cases.title}
</Link>
```

I need to store cases["_id"] coming from API to localStorage and onClick it should redirect to new tab but that's not working.
Can someone tell me how to fix this issue ?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/2188

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`target="_blank"` affects the browser's default navigation.

By calling `e.preventDefault()`, your click handler prevents that from happening.